# Fax Server on a Domain Controller

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, remote, fax

So I have this Fax number attached to a modem inside a Windows 2012 R2 DC.

I followed the steps on: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134193.aspx to install and configure the Fax Service. Everything on the DC is working fine, I'm able to send and receive faxes just good using my domain admin account.

The problem is that I can't connect to the DC server over the network using the "Windows Fax and Scan" tool, whenever I try initiate the fax setup on a remote machine and connect to the fax server, the following error appears:

[image: Fax Setup Error]

Not even the domain admin can connect, so I suspect that it has something to do with being a DC, but I could be wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't install this kind of thing on a Domain Controller. Applications like these are what member servers are for.

Comment: Totally agree with you, I would never install anything on a DC if I had the option, tell that to people the keep cutting our budget and demand that we do magic with so little, sigh...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the fax machine must be shared on the fax server, exactly the same way as if you're sharing a printer to the network users. Sharing the fax machine will insure that users are able to access it.

Done that and I'm happily delegating the fax work to our secretary now.

Comment: Do you have any link reference? @NoorKhaldi

Comment: There you go: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134193(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_Step2

Comment: Thanks tho, I done that but still can't connect. I was wondering what the problem is.